Class variable overtake check bypassed by module method?
I'm learning Ruby and I'm digging into the topic of class variables.
I know that their behavior is confusing and that they should be avoided when possible, but nonetheless I'd like to build a mental model about how they work.
The strange thing I've encountered is what follows.
This snippet of code raises the exception class variable @@cvar of C is overtaken by Mod (RuntimeError):
module Mod
  @@cvar = 1
end

class C
  @@cvar = 0

  include Mod

  def meth
    @@cvar
  end
end

p C.new.meth

This makes sense to me, since the C's class variable is overwritten by the one in Mod.
But if I move the method to the module itself, like this:
module Mod
  @@cvar = 1

  def meth
    @@cvar
  end
end

class C
  @@cvar = 0

  include Mod
end

p C.new.meth

the code happily runs without errors, and prints 1 as expected.
Can someone explain to me why this happens? Why is there a difference in behavior between the case with the method defined in C and the case of the method mixed in from Mod?
Even a pointer to some relevant documentation is very much appreciated.

According to this comment: "Overtaking a class variable only raises on read (because of how class variable lookup is done on MRI, always look all ancestors without caching)".
So if you add @@cvar after the Mod inclusion the error does occur. e.g.
class C
  @@cvar = 0
  include Mod
  @@cvar #Runtime Error
end

Since neither include Mod nor C.new.meth actually attempt to read @@cvar in the scope of C it does not see it as an "overtaking", I guess.
Details on the change in 3.0 can be found Here
Another strange observation is that C still recognizes @@cvar as a class variable of C
C.class_variables(false) = [:@@cvar]

In previous versions of ruby (< 3.0) if the class variable was referenced in the context of the "sub class" (now a RuntimeError) then the class variable disappeared or rather was correctly attributed to the hierarchy e.g.
module Mod
  @@cvar = 1
end
class C
  @@cvar = 0
  include Mod
end
C.class_variables(false)
#=> [:@@cvar]

class C; @@cvar; end

C.class_variables(false)
#=> []

